# Do nodes of a Alwayson cluster impact each other?

Tags: sql, alwayson

I have an AlwaysOn group on two sql servers. Sql1 is the primary and SQL2 is the secondary replica.  it's async mode and read-only allowed. My SQL2 (secondary replica) is only for reporting, so I set the failover level to 1 (which means no failover at all)   I have some heave SQL jobs running on SQL2, sometimes these jobs caused disk not responding. does this impact SQL1 as well?  I think the answer is yes, but how?   I always found these two servers not responding or extremely slow at the same time.  I have almost nothing heavy running on SQL1 and the databased in AG group are small databases.
Can someone explain how nodes impact each other?